# Dismissing A ModalViewController With PageCurl

Tags: ios4, modalviewcontroller, page-curl

I've a modal view controller presented with page curl style. Everything works fine, but, if I click the page curled at top of the page, the modal view gets dismissed without any input.

Now, I could accept this behavior but I need to do some operation when it happens. How can I catch the event to do my stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are talking about the half-page curl effect? If so, you could probably catch the event of it dismissing the modal view by implementing/overriding the following method in the ViewController that is doing the presenting...

```
- (void)dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated {

NSLog(@"Executing Own operation before dismissing!");

[super dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:animated];
}
```

Do your operation either before of after the call the the super method depending on if you want to execute it before or after the view is dismissed. I didn't get a chance to try this out so let me know if it works.

Comment: You're assuming right. I added in the view an image of a page corner, where the user should swipe. So, I added a gesture recognizer only when the user swipes on the corner. Now, if the user tap into the row of a Table in the MVC, everything works fine, the delegate gets called and I'm able to remove the gesture correctly, but if I tap on the page, I can't remove the gesture. Actually with your method I receive a SIGBART message whenI call [[self view] removeGestureRecognizer:gestRec]

Comment: without access to your code I can't tell you why your getting a SIGBART. If my code worked though and helped out in some way I would appreciate a vote up. trying to get some rep...